If I use Spring Data JPA without @Transactional, will the entity not be in a Managed state in the persistence context?
I used Spring Data JPA's JpaRepository(3.2.2), and after checking the implementation, I found out that it uses jakarta.persistence.EntityManager to perform find operations. As far as I know, when entitymanager.find is called, the entity is fetched into a managed state in the persistence context. and also i find out this answer.
However, I've heard that entities only become persistent under a transaction.
In conclusion, I'm curious whether my code below guarantees that the entity is in a managed state.
Controller
    @GetMapping("individual/check")
    fun getIndividualaccountCreateEligibility(
        @RequestAttribute actor: Actor,
    ): Response<Boolean> {
        return Response(
            data = accountService.canCreateIndividualAccount(
                actor.user?.id,
            ),
        )
    }

Service
    fun canCreateIndividualAccount(userId: Long?): Boolean {
        val users: List<AccountEntity>
        if (userId != null) {
            accounts = accountRepository.findAllByUserId(userId)
        } else {
            return false
        }

        val ownerAccountIds = accounts
            .filter { it.isOwner }
            .map { it.accountInfo.id }

        return AccountInfoRepository.findAllById(ownerAccountIds)
            .none() { it.isIndividual() && it.deletedAt == null } 
    }

I expected that entities would become managed when performing a find operation, even though I am not using @Transactional for this query. However, my colleague has informed me that without @Transactional, the entities would be in a detached state.

Your colleague is correct. as without an encompassing transaction the session to which the entities belong will be ended after the find. Hence your entities will be detached at that point. Now it might still work sort of due to the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter which opens an EntityManager very early on, but it might not issue a commit due to the lack of an @Transactional and thus no clear point on when to flush and persist. You still would need a transaction to persist even if the entities would be managed, without a transaction no persistence.
